# Can't randomly generate list with functions with random.shuffle

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a simple command line game in python. The only problem is that when I want to make the question randomly display, they don't. I will show you the current method I'm using to pick the functions (questions) out.

```
while 1:
    questionList = [Question1(), Question2(), Question3(), Question4(), Question5()]
    newList = random.shuffle(questionList)
    print(newList.pop())
    print("Checking question list\n")
```

I've also used random.sample and no luck with that either :/

Please help ^-^

Comment: `random.shuffle()` doesn't return a new list; it randomizes the existing list.

Comment: When asking questions about errors in your code, please describe the intended behavior and what actually happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind that in this case the functions in the array, i.e. `Question1(), Question2(), Question3(), Question4(), Question5()` will get called first. It is the *results* of these evaluations that will be assigned as the elements of `questionList`.

If you want to have the functions themselves as the elements of an array, you need to remove the parenthesis:

```
questionList = [Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5]
```

Then your original code will work with a small modification:

```
random.shuffle(questionList)
print(questionList.pop()())
```

Note the extra pair of parenthesis and that the `newList` variable has disappeared.

What happens here is the following. When Python sees `()` after an identifier, it tries to call that identifier immediately. So basically `Question1()` would get evaluated and its result assigned as the first element of `questionList`. `Question2()` as the second, and so on. However, if you leave out the `()`, the functions themselves will be assigned as the elements of `questionList`. Then you just need to call the "popped" function and that is what the extra `()` after `pop()` does.

As John Gordon mentioned in his comment, `random.shuffle(questionList)` modifies `questionList` in place and returns `None`. When you write something like

```
newList = random.shuffle(questionList)
```

the returned value (i.e. `None`) is actually assigned to `newList`. So the value of `newList` in this case will be simply `None`. Instead, you should just use `questionList` after you shuffled it. That is why you need to remove `newList`.

However, you can still simplify your code by using `random.choice()` instead of using `random.shuffle()` and then `pop()`, as I suggested in my original answer:

```
while 1:
    questionList = [Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5]
    print(random.choice(questionList)())
    print("Checking question list\n")
```

Good luck!

Comment: that makes sense of why the questions are still being displayed in order. So, do I have to move the print(random.choice(questionList)) up before the variable is defined? EDIT: That didnt work either :/ I really don't know to do on this one.

Comment: What I think you're saying is that the functions are run before they are assigned to questionList. Not sure how to fix this since this is my first python project that I've put actual time and effort into

Comment: Ahhhh Thank You very much. Now all I need to do is make it so that when a question is picked it is never picked again. I see you mention .pop but I don't know where to put in the lines of while 1:
    questionList = [Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5]
    print(random.choice(questionList)())
    print("Checking question list\n")

Comment: Oh, in case you don't want to repeat the Questions, you indeed need to use random.shuffle and .pop(). Just use the first two code snippets in my answer and you should be fine.

Comment: I've gotten closer to the solution with using what you just suggested. But, even though I no longer get any errors, the questions are displayed randomly but keep repeating, like they are never crossed off the list. Been trying many different orders and command but can't seem to figure this one out... ;-;

Answer (score 0):

To expand on John Gordon's comment this is what you need:

```
while 1:
    questionList = [Question1(), Question2(), Question3(), Question4(), Question5()]
    random.shuffle(questionList)
    print(questionList.pop())
    print("Checking question list\n")
```

Comment: That still doesn't work... Still displays the Questions in order of 1, 2, 3, etc. ;-;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shuffle function from the random module:

```
while 1:
    questionList = [Question1(), Question2(), Question3(), Question4(), Question5()]
    newList = questionList 
    random.shuffle(questionList)
    print(newList.pop(newList.index(holder)))
    print("Checking question list\n")
```

The reason I created a copy of the original list is it looks like you want to retain the original list of questions (whereas pop would remove the item chosen from the list.) If that's not the case you can remove this line.

Careful though, since the while loop here would essentially keep going until the program is manually forced to stop.

Comment: Maybe I'm putting the right code in the wrong place because those still don't seem to work correctly :/ I put these lines of code after I defined all the functions, since if I put it above it wont know what the functions are.